# How to create a custom user property for firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-console

The help section on the firebase console says that

> Firebase app can have up to 25 uniquely named user properties (case-sensitive). You should use properties for non-variable attributes, such as “handedness=right”, “spender=true”.

In the [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/properties) a property is said be to set this way

```
mFirebaseAnalytics.setUserProperty("favorite_food", mFavoriteFood);
```

Does this mean that for every user property named **k** and having a value **v**, we need to create a user property in the console as "**k=v**" and set it in the code by **setUserProperty(k,v)**? So, for a user property called "favorite_food" having the possible values as "pasta" and "pizza", one needs to create two new user properties in the console as "favorite_food=pasta" and "favorite_food=pizza" and set it by, say, setUserProperty("favorite_food","pasta")?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For every User Property named **k**, you need to register an entry in the "User Properties" tab in Firebase Analytics.  For every user with User Property value **k=v**, you need to call `setUserProperty(k,v)`.

After calling `setUserProperty(k,v)` (and after logging some events), you will be able to filter your Analytics reports by applying a User Property filter for **k=v** (favorite_food=pizza) .

Comment: Cool, thanks! The documentation is somewhat confusing at present.

Comment: I've done the above, but only the first user property gets registered. If in I set more custom user properties in the same screen, they aren't registered in console. I do see them in Logcat. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Creating an entry for User Property k in the console will allow you to
filter based on k=v0, k=v1, ... for all valid values of k.